# How can I make notification without an obligation to close the pr0blem?

Tags: zabbix

I need to receive a notification when authentication on the client happens.
I have an item with key:

```
log[/var/log/auth.log,(sshd.*)?(Accepted)]
```

Also I have trigger with key:

```
{test.test.ru:log[/var/log/auth.log,(sshd.*)?(Accepted)].str(Accepted,#1)}=1
```

I need that there will be only notification without raising a problem. With my config I always should deactivate the problem and I receive a second notification I don't need. How can I make notification without an obligation to close the problem or to receive second notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that this is impossible... What meets my requirements most is to make a specific action for this trigger and do not make a recovery step for it.

Answer (score 0):

In the trigger configuration, you can select "Problem Event Generation Mode" = "Multiple" to have multiple problem / notification.

An Action can have no Recovery Operation and works just fine.

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/triggers/trigger